# undefined method [] for nil:NilClass when trying to pull a value of a hash - inspect shows it's there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, null

So, I was migrating a rails app to a newer version of the gems, ruby version etc, and I ended up with one problem:

I have a hash @values that I pull from in my controller, and whenever i try to do so, I get

```
undefined method [] for nil:NilClass
```

But when I throw in a logger to grab the value via @values.inspect I can clearly see the keys and values. I am sure it must be something very obvious I am missing, and I found another user that had this problem and solved it, but I can't seem to make it work. The full code is

```
if @values[:true_value]
  # do some stuff
end
```

And I get the undefined method [] for nil:NilClass error on the if line.

Thank you for taking the time to help me out

EDIT:

I have a method:
    def GH
     {
       :true_value=>true
     }
    end

So when using it in the controller, I load @values as:

```
@values = GH
```

Comment: Show the code where `@values` is being set. Also, have you verified that when `@values.inspect` is printed, it is the same instance where you are getting the error?

Comment: I have verified that it's the same instance, and the code for getting it is :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [present](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F)..just like we do usually for checking `params`

```
 if @values[:true_value].present?
  # do some stuff
end
```

Comment: I tried a few things and later found that by rendering partial views some variables didn't get passed on as a mailed was involved, and a beginner like me didn't pick that up. Thanks for all your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have methods that begin with a capital letter; these are reserved for constants.

Rewrite your method as:

```
def gh
  { :true_value => true }
end
```

on 3 lines (not one line as in your question) and

```
@values = gh
```

Comment: My bad, it was lower case, just typed it out incorrectly over here

Answer (score 0):

method name must be in small, instead of **GH** it should be **gh**

1. def gh; { :true_value=>true }; end
2. @values = gh
3. @values[:true_value]
   => true

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: It was in small chars, i had typed it wrong in stackoverflow. The @values val was being pased on to a view that was called by a mailed that didnt pass on the var.